# Effect of using of brackets in Cartesian Product?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ and $B$ are any sets, then is it that the cartesian product of $A \times A \times B$ does not equal the cartesian product of $A \times ( A \times B)$?

Comment: And what are you thoughts ?

Comment: Is an ordered triple $(a,b,c)$ the same as the ordered pair $(a,(b,c))$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the Cartesian product of sets associative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556187/is-the-cartesian-product-of-sets-associative)

Answer (score 0):

The definition of *Cartesian Product* goes as follows.

> **Definition:** Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty sets. The **Cartesian Product** of $A$ and $B$ is the set 
> $$A \times B = \{(a,b) \mid a \in A \wedge b \in B\},$$
> where $(a,b)$ denotes an ordered pair.

To understand better what we are doing here with ordered pairs, let’s go back to the definition of ordered pair given by Kuratowski.

> **Definition:** Let $a, b$ be any objects. We define the **ordered pair** of $a$ and $b$, denoted by $(a,b)$ to be the set 
> $$(a,b) = \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}.$$

Now, let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be non-empty sets. Consider now the Cartesian Products $A \times (B \times C)$ and $(A \times B) \times C$.

If $a \in A$, $b \in B$ and $c \in C$, then $(a,(b,c))$ denotes an element of $A \times (B \times C)$ and $((a,b),c)$ denotes an element of $(A \times B) \times C$.

Strictly speaking, $(a,(b,c)) \neq ((a,b),c).$ You can check this by Kuratowski’s definition.

$$(a,(b,c)) = \{\{a\},\{a,(b,c)\}\} = \{\{a\},\{a,\{\{b\},\{b,c\}\}\}\}.$$

$$((a,b),c) = \{\{(a,b)\},\{(a,b),c\}\} = \{\{\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}\},\{\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\},c\}\}.$$

Note that $\{a\} \in (a,(b,c))$ but $\{a\} \notin ((a,b),c)$ so they are different by definition of equality of sets. Which means that $A \times (B \times C) \neq (A \times B) \times C$.

Although, we can easily see that $A \times (B \times C) \cong (A \times B) \times C$, i.e., $A \times (B \times C)$ and $(A \times B) \times C$ are **isomorphic**.

> Consider $f:A \times (B \times C) \to (A \times B) \times C$ defined by $f((a,(b,c))) = ((a,b),c)$ for all $(a,(b,c)) \in A \times (B \times C)$.

The fact that they are isomorphic allows us to treat them as “equal”, as being the same set. This proves that the Cartesian Product is Associative **up to an isomorphism** and so it makes sense to define $A \times B \times C$ to be equal to $A \times (B \times C)$ or $(A \times B) \times C$. And so we defined it as follows.

$$A \times B \times C = \{(a,b,c) \mid a \in A \wedge b \in B \wedge c \in C\}.$$

Finally, note that this definition is indeed unambiguous from what we have just seen.

Comment: Technically, ordered triples are typically defined to be $((a,b),c)$ or $(a,(b,c))$ (depending on the author), so $A\times B\times C$ as you've defined is either $(A\times B)\times C$ or $A\times (B\times C)$; we just don't often care which. It's still not correct to say it's associative, just associative *up to isomorphism* (natural isomorphism, even).

Comment: @MaliceVidrine thank you for that comment! In fact, I should have stated that, I already edited my answer! Thank you